Model comparison or beta coefficient of full model?
my question is a rather theoretical one. I have to decide in advance how I want to analyze my data (I'm going with the lme4 package in R) and feel torn between doing a model comparison by creating two nested models (m1) that differ in one fixed effect (m2) and just running the full mixed model (m2). Either way, I would look mainly at the p-value (either of the output of anova(m1, m2) or of the beta coefficient of the fixed effect in m2 that I am most interested in). Does anyone know if it is even possible to obtain different p-values for the two different approaches? If the results are always the same anyway (which is my experience so far), what makes you decide for or against one or the other approach? I have seen both in psychological papers and feel confused about it. I would really appreciate it if anyone can share their experience or line of thought regarding those two approaches.
Thank you so much for reading this post so far.

It's true that a comparison between two nested models is often exactly equivalent to testing the null hypothesis about a particular coefficient (e.g. $\beta_1 = 0$), in which case it is usually more convenient to look at the coefficients (since that only requires fitting one model — the full model — rather than two).

if you're using linear mixed models then there are finite-size corrections available (aka "computing [denominator] degrees of freedom", e.g. Satterthwaite or Kenward-Roger); these can be applied either to individual coefficients (e.g. lmerTest package) or to model comparisons or sets of parameters (e.g. pbkrtest::KRmodcomp)
if you want to test the joint effect of several parameters (e.g. all of the different coefficients that determine the effect of a multi-level factor/categorical predictor), it may be easier to do the model comparison (although it may also be possible to do (e.g.) a Wald joint test of a set of parameters, e.g. see aod::wald.test())
if your model has interaction terms you have to be careful about the meaning of a test of an individual main-effect coefficient (search for principle of marginality here or elsewhere); explicitly comparing models may make it easier to understand what you're actually testing
for mixed models and especially for generalized linear models, the tests report by R's summary() method are usually Wald tests, which make an approximation/assumption that only holds exactly for plain linear models (quadratic log-likelihood function). Model comparisons are usually likelihood ratio tests, which are more accurate in this case. (However, Wald tests for fixed effect parameters in linear mixed models are often pretty accurate  ...)
when comparing mixed models you always have to make sure that you are comparing models fitted with maximum likelihood, not restricted maximum likelihood.  lme4 and pbkrtest automatically re-fit REML models with ML when doing such comparisons, but other packages/approaches may not be as careful ...

library(lmerTest)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fm0 <- update(fm1, . ~ . - Days)
coef(summary(fm1))["Days", "Pr(>|t|)"]  ## 3.623824e-06
coef(summary(fm1, ddf = "Kenward-Roger"))["Days", "Pr(>|t|)"]  ## 3.263808e-06
anova(fm1, fm0)  ## p-value: 1.226e-06
pbkrtest::KRmodcomp(fm1, fm0)  ## 3.263808e-06

The odd one out here is anova(), which does a likelihood ratio test (i.e. no finite-size correction); this has a fairly large effect since the ddf are approximately 7 here (e.g. the upper critical value for a t distribution with 17 df is 2.11, vs. 1.96 for a Normal distribution).

Thank you so much for this very comprehensive answer, I couldn't have wished for more!
